# Trying to migrate to verify API for the Authy but getting error verification service was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

trying to migrate from the Authy API to the verify API following the docs I've tried to run this:

```rb
check = self.twilio_client.verify.v2.services(self.service_sid).verifications.create(to: parsed_number.international, channel: via)
```

Error message:
"The requested resource /Services/VAXXXXXXXXX/Verifications was not found"
I've used that number from the Twilio console app. It seemed like we have a configured service with that service_sid. What am I missing?